# How to send variable from php to a bash script that is asking for user input and need to click enter?

Tags: python, php, shell

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import os
import sys

client=sys.argv[1]
homeDir="/home/vpnUsers"

os.system("cd /etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/")
os.system("./easyrsa build-client-full %s" %(client))
os.system("cp /etc/openvpn/client-template.txt %s/%s.ovpn" %(homeDir,client))
```

At **os.system("./easyrsa build-client-full %s" %(client))** if I run it manually on terminal it ask 2 times for a password, so If I do it manually I can enter a password, click enter and its done. How can I do this but with python?

Lets supose the sys.argv[2] its the password and it should be written at the this command when it ask for password.

Ps: the args come from php.

Comment: have you try with stream? `some_command < file_with_parameters`

Comment: At php I only do **$output = exec("/path/to/file.sh $client 2>&1");** (with escapeshellarg obviously). I don't really understand what you asking. How can I send more parameters to that exact **os.system**?

Comment: I mean If **os.system("./easyrsa build-client-full %s" %(client))** is asking for user input, is it possible to send args to that questions?

Comment: If your command asking for 2 args put them to the file (separate them with white sign) and run it `command < file_with_args`. It should works!

Answer (score 1):

Solved it!

[Pexpect](https://pexpect.readthedocs.io/en/stable/)

This library will talk with the script. Easy to use.

> pip install pexpect

Then on your script python just import it

> import pexpect

Example code for my situation

```
 localcmd='/path/to/script/easyrsa build-client-full "arg"'

 def localOutput(localcmd):
        child = pexpect.spawn (localcmd)
        child.expect ('Enter PEM pass phrase:')
        child.sendline ('password')
        child.expect ('Verifying - Enter PEM pass phrase:')
        child.sendline ('password')
        child.expect(pexpect.EOF)
        return child.before  

localout=localOutput(localcmd)
```